# Angular Material Tooltip alignment issue off-screen

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

Here is my code: Does anyone experience the same problem? Off-screen on Chrome-Mozzila etc why?

```
  <md-menu>
            <md-button class="md-icon-button" ng-click="$mdOpenMenu()">
                <md-icon class="icon-18">settings</md-icon>
                <md-tooltip>Page Settings</md-tooltip>
            </md-button>
  </md-menu>
```

Comment: That's not much to work with, the CSS and the surrounding HTML would be useful to add to your question as probably the source of the problem.

Comment: Can you provide a Codepen or JSFiddle with your code in it ??

Comment: I succeded to solve the problem. We have to use <md-tooltip md-direction="bottom">Page Settings</md-tooltip>